# Emacs and JSlint

Tags: flycheck, javascript

Is there a way to make Emacs [flycheck](http://www.flycheck.org/en/latest/) run [JSlint](http://www.jslint.com/) (not flymake, not JShint, and not eslint) on the current file?

Comment: You have to write your own checker http://www.flycheck.org/en/latest/developer/developing.html#writing-the-checker

Comment: Thanks @caisah ; I ended up using jshint (with flycheck) as it pretty much follows jslint guidelines :)